# Using PhantomJS to print user activity

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, screenshot

In the company where I work there are many agents making calls and entering information into our system. I would like to know if it is possible for a boss **to take a screenshot of the user's screen at any time of the day to know what activity the user is doing**.

I know this can be done with PhantomJS, but I think it's used to make a screenshot of an external website.

Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: It's possible, but not with PhantomJS.

Comment: But with which?

Comment: It's not a task for a browser, but for a special utility: https://www.google.com/search?q=monitor+user+activity+screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are  looking for is an application called [TimeSnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com). It records your screen every few seconds, and it also categorizes active applications/urls so it can calculate a productivity score.